# Problems trying to construct a wrapper measuring function call time

Tags: c++, templates, wrapper, variant, variadic

I'm implementing some data structures, each supporting a set of commands such as `INSERT value`.

I've used a tokenizer to generate a vector that holds each word/value.

I want to be able to output to a .txt file the time *every* function call took, plus what the function returned **if** it *does* return something.

For example, if the command is `INSERT AVLTREE 4`, I want to just output the time calling `avl.insert(4)` took.
If the command is `SEARCH AVLTREE 4`, I want to output the time calling `avl.search(4)` took, as well as its result (e.g. `"SUCCESS"` or `"FAILURE"`).

There are probably many things wrong with the following code, but here's what I came up with:

I made two files (.cpp/.hpp) which contain the following self-hacked function wrapper, and also a variant as well as a struct:

```cpp
// WRAPPER CPP
// file: wrap.cpp


#include "wrap.hpp"


#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/variant.hpp>


using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::time_point;
using std::chrono::nanoseconds;

using std::string;
using std::to_string;

using std::forward;

using boost::get;
using boost::static_visitor;
using boost::apply_visitor;


// I'm overloading std::to_string, so it works on std::strings as well.
string to_string(const string &value)
{
    return value;
}

// I want to apply to_string on whatever is inside my variant.
class to_string_visitor : public static_visitor<>
{
    public:
        template <typename T>
        void operator()(T & operand) const
        {
            to_string(operand);
        }
};

// Takes two points in time and returns the time 
// between them in nanoseconds.
const nanoseconds::rep duration(const nanoseconds tpoints_difference) noexcept
{
    const auto result = tpoints_difference.count();
    return result;
}

// Generates a point in time.
const high_resolution_clock::time_point timeNow(void) noexcept
{
    const auto result = high_resolution_clock::now();
    return result;
}

// Here's where's the problematic magic happens:
// The ret boolean is set to true if the function F returns a value,
// otherwise, it is set to false.
//
// Variadic arguments are being taken and then std::forwarded to F.
template<typename F, typename... Args>
const output wrapper(bool ret, F function, Args&&... args) noexcept
{
        // Generate a point in time, t1.
    const high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = timeNow();

        // If F returns a result,
    if (ret == true)
    {
                // assign it to result (my variant).
        result = function(forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    else
    {
                // just call F with Args forwarded.
        function(forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

        // Generate another point in time, t2 and
        // count the difference between t2 - t1.
    const auto elapsed = duration(timeNow() - t1);

        // Make whatever is inside result a string
        // using std::to_string.
    apply_visitor(to_string_visitor(), result);

        // My struct
    output out;

        // which contains the time elapsed and
        // the result returned
    out.time = elapsed;
    out.result = get<string>(result);

        // I can theoretically use both time elapsed and
        // result returned however I want. Hooray!..almost:(
    return out;
}
```

Here is the variant `result`:

```cpp
// These are all the types a data structure function may return.
variant<int, unsigned, uint32_t, size_t, graph_size, string> result = 0;
```

`graph_size`, just for reference:

```cpp
struct graph_size
{
    unsigned vertices; //Number of vertices that the Graph currently contains
    unsigned edges;    //Number of edges that the Graph currently contains
};
```

And, finally, the `output` struct:

```cpp
typedef struct output
{
    double time;          // function call time
    string result;        // what function returned

        // notice that if function returned nothing,
        // result will be an empty string.
    output() : time(0), result("") {}
} output;
```

I'm trying to use `wrapper` like so:

```cpp
AVL avl;
// stuff
auto out = wrapper(true, avl.insert, 4);
```

I get the following error:

```
invalid use of non-static member function 'void AVL::insert(int)'
```

And here's a bonus one which should hint me towards what I botched but  just can't quite grasp it:

```
no matching function for call to 'wrapper(bool, <unresolved overloaded function type>, unsigned int&)'
```

Any thoughts?

I appreciate all time spent in advance :)

EDIT 1: The question title may not be very suitable, I'll merrily change if you have something good in mind

Comment: ```auto out = wrapper(true, avl.insert, 4); ```
here is your problem. You are trying to pass to wrapper a function which is a non static member of avl class. Unless static, the method needs an object to operate on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need different behaviour depending of return type, you might use specialization/SFINAE, something like:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto wrapper(F function, Args&&... args) noexcept
-> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<void, std::invoke_result_t<F, Args&&...>>::value, output>
{
    const high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = timeNow();
    function(forward<Args>(args)...);
    const auto elapsed = duration(timeNow() - t1);

    output out;
    out.time = elapsed;
    out.result = ""; // void return
    return out;
}

template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto wrapper(F function, Args&&... args) noexcept
-> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<void, std::invoke_result_t<F, Args&&...>>::value, output>
{
    const high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = timeNow();
    auto result = function(forward<Args>(args)...);
    const auto elapsed = duration(timeNow() - t1);

    output out;
    out.time = elapsed;
    out.result = to_string(result);
    return out;
}
```

with possible usage:

```
AVL avl;

auto out = wrapper([&](){ return avl.insert(4);});
```

Comment: Thanks for the very informative and helpful answer!
I'm still trying to make SFINAE work, I'm getting errors that it's used but never defined.
Does it have to do with [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904099/why-sfinae-enable-if-works-from-inside-class-definition-but-not-from-outside)?
Should I just accept and file a new question?

Comment: File new question seems reasonable as you have to provide problematic code. (and editing this one seems changing the question too much). You can then for answers for the other question to know if this one is fine for you. (you might link questions together).

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in a corner case of your `wrapper()` function usage. It's quite tricky to make it work with member functions and possibly with `void`-returning functions (see **Jarod42**'s excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56685640/7151494) on that). This:

```
wrapper(true, avl.insert, 4);
```

will not compile for several reasons. Not only `avl.insert` is invalid, but even if you tried to pass a member function by a pointer and pass an object to call it, like so:

```
wrapper(true, &AVL::insert, avl, 4);
```

it still won't compile, but now due to *how you invoke it inside `wrapper`*.

The workaround is to use a suitable tool for this kind of job - [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke). It correctly handles free functions, member functions etc. Example usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct foo {
    void bar(int x) {
        std::cout << x;
    }
};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
void wrapper(F f, Args&&... args) {
    std::invoke(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void free_bar() {
    std::cout << "free";
}

int main() {
    foo f;
    wrapper(&foo::bar, f, 1); // pass a pointer to member function and the instance itself, then arguments
    wrapper(free_bar);
}
```

Notice how the code correctly handles each case. `std::invoke` just *does the right thing*.